# How to combine two Maps into one with maintaining the duplicate values

Tags: java, list, arraylist, merge, hashmap

I have two hashmaps "`map0 and map1`", both of them holds keys of type `Point` and values of type `Double` as shown below.

I am sure that the key will never be duplicate but the values could be and I want to add both of "`map0 and map1`" into one `Hashmap` so that
I do not lose the duplicate values "I want to keep the duplicate values". After i checked some questions in this website, I used .`putAll()` method as shown below in the code, but the problem is, when I combined both maps "map0, map1" into one combined map, I lost the duplicate values as shown below in the results as map0 has value of 20 and map1 has value of 20 as well!

Please let me know how to combine both maps into one without losing the duplicate values

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<Point, Double> map0 = new HashMap<Point, Double>();
    HashMap<Point, Double> map1 = new HashMap<Point, Double>();

    map0.put(new Point(32,59), (double) 56);
    map0.put(new Point(398,3), (double) 20);
    map0.put(new Point(3,3), (double) 209);

    map1.put(new Point(32,596), (double) 561);
    map1.put(new Point(396,311), (double) 20);
    map1.put(new Point(35,34), (double) 2099);

    System.out.println("map0.size:"+map0.size());
    System.out.println("map1.size:"+map1.size());

    HashMap<Point, Double> combine = new HashMap<Point, Double>();

    combine.putAll(map0);
    combine.putAll(map1);
    ValueComparator vc = new ValueComparator(combine);
    TreeMap<Point, Double> tree= new TreeMap<Point, Double>(vc);

    tree.putAll(combine);
    System.out.println("tree.size:"+tree.size());
    System.out.println("tree_sorted:"+tree);

}

static class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Point> {

    private HashMap<Point, Double> map = null;

    public ValueComparator(HashMap<Point, Double> map) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int compare(Point arg0, Point arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return Double.compare(this.map.get(arg0), this.map.get(arg1));
        /*
        if (this.map.get(arg0) >= this.map.get(arg1)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
        */
    }
}
```

**output**:

```
map0.size:3
map1.size:3
tree.size:5
tree_sorted:{{398.0, 3.0}=20.0, {32.0, 59.0}=56.0, {3.0, 3.0}=209.0, {32.0, 596.0}=561.0, {35.0, 34.0}=2099.0}
```

Comment: You will need to switch to `Map<Point, List<Double>>`, won't you?

Comment: @bmargulies do u mean i should declare "combinedMap" as Map<Point, List<Double>>??? if yes, what is the next step please

Comment: Why do you need this: ValueComparator vc = new ValueComparator(combine);
    TreeMap<Point, Double> tree= new TreeMap<Point, Double>(vc);?

Comment: Use a MultiMap class: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html

Comment: Just to get this right: There will not be any overlap in the _keys_ of the two maps, but only in the _values_. So, what is the problem? The result will contain both keys with value `20`. Do you want those keys with the same value be grouped in some way?

Comment: @tobias_k i want to combine two maps into one, then the one that contains both maps should be sorted. the problem now is, after sorting the  map that combines both maps, i lose the duplicate values, and i want to keep them

Comment: Please share your `Point` class to. How many values `combine` contains after both maps are added?

Comment: @plastique point class is an already implemented class in opencv library i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two objects in `TreeMap` which are 'equal' from the standpoint of given comparator. It is explicitly stated in [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> This is so because the Map interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal.

Your further use of sorted collection is not stated in the question so I presume that sorted `List` will be enough for you. I also recommend to extend the `Point`class to associate value with it. It will better suits to this use.

Also your comparator was not implemented the right way. It should not have the outside map reference.

So consider following code:

```
public class Example {

public static class ValuedPoint extends Point {
  private double value;

  public ValuedPoint(double x, double y, double value) {
    super(x, y);
    this.value = value;
  }

  public double getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "{" + x + ", " + y + ", " + value + "}";
  }
}

private static class ValueComparator implements Comparator<ValuedPoint> {

  public int compare(ValuedPoint arg0, ValuedPoint arg1) {
    return Double.compare(arg0.getValue(), arg1.getValue());
   }
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Set<ValuedPoint> set0 = new HashSet<ValuedPoint>();
  Set<ValuedPoint> set1 = new HashSet<ValuedPoint>();

  set0.add(new ValuedPoint(32, 59, 56));
  set0.add(new ValuedPoint(398, 3, 20));
  set0.add(new ValuedPoint(3, 3, 209));

  set1.add(new ValuedPoint(32, 596, 561));
  set1.add(new ValuedPoint(396, 311, 20));
  set1.add(new ValuedPoint(35, 34, 2099));

  System.out.println("set0.size:" + set0.size());
  System.out.println("set1.size:" + set1.size());

  Set<ValuedPoint> combined = new HashSet<ValuedPoint>();

  combined.addAll(set0);
  combined.addAll(set1);
  System.out.println("combined size:" + combined.size());

  ValueComparator comparator = new ValueComparator();

  List<ValuedPoint> sortedList = new ArrayList<ValuedPoint>(combined);
  Collections.sort(sortedList, comparator);

  System.out.println("list size:" + sortedList.size());
  System.out.println("sortedList:" + sortedList);
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
set0.size:3
set1.size:3
combined size:6
list size:6
sortedList:[{398.0, 3.0, 20.0}, {396.0, 311.0, 20.0}, {32.0, 59.0,56.0}, {3.0, 3.0, 209.0}, {32.0, 596.0, 561.0}, {35.0, 34.0, 2099.0}]
```

Comment: i appreciate your effort and time, but I wouldlike to tell you that, the class Point is a builit-in clas in opencv libs i am using

Comment: I know. The proposed solution works with it. I'm only extending the opencv `Point` class. You may still use any `ValuedPoint` instance as `Point` instance. It is one of the fundamental principles of OOP.

Comment: @thanks for your answer, but i just could not understand what you said in you answer concerning "Also your comparator was not implemented the right way. It should not have the outside map reference"!! would you please clarify

Comment: Your comparator works as intended. But its `compare(...)` results depends on some internal state. It is not computed from compared arguments directly. So when comparators internal state change (somewhat), results of `compare(...)` might change or even fail.

Answer (score 1):

You define the comparison criteria for your keys (`Point`) is the related value (`Double`), thus the two points with value 20 are identical to your Comparator.

If you want to keep the duplicates, change the Comparator (i.e. your definition of equality) or use a different data structure, as a map does not allow for duplicate keys.

Comment: isn't there any way to keep the duplicate values even after comparing the elements in the map that combines both of the two?